# If $\lambda\neq0$ is a limit ordinal, then $1+\lambda=\lambda$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals

For example if $\lambda=\omega$ then $1+\omega=\omega$

Indeed $1+\omega=\bigcup_{\alpha\in\omega}(1+\alpha)$
but the sum is commutative in $\omega$ so that $1+\omega=\bigcup_{\alpha\in\omega}(\alpha+1)$

Now obviously $\alpha\in(\alpha+1)\subseteq\bigcup_{\alpha\in\omega}(\alpha+1)$ so that $\omega\subseteq 1+\omega$ but if $\beta\in 1+\omega$ then $\beta\in\alpha+1$ so that $\beta$ is a natural number and so that it is an element of $\omega$ and thus $1+\omega\subseteq \omega$.

Finally we conlude that
$$
1+\omega=\omega
$$

So how prove that
$$
1+\lambda=\lambda
$$
if $\lambda$ is a limit ordinal strictly greater than $\omega$?

Comment: Sorry, I'll fix it right away.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [For what ordinals does $1+\alpha=\alpha$ hold? For what ordinals does $2\alpha=\alpha$ hold?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2780529/272831)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In fact if $\lambda\geq\omega$, then $1+\lambda=\lambda$, regardless of whether $\lambda$ is a limit ordinal or not. Let's prove this by induction.

The base case is $\lambda=\omega$, you wrote in the question that you already know that $1+\omega=\omega$, so I won't add anything.

In the successor case suppose that $\lambda=\beta+1$. Then $$1+\lambda=1+(\beta+1)=(1+\beta)+1=\beta+1=\lambda,$$ where $1+\beta=\beta$ holds by inductive hypothesis.

In the limit case we have, by definition, $$1+\lambda=\sup_{\beta<\lambda}1+\beta=\sup_{\beta<\lambda}\beta=\lambda,$$
where $1+\beta=\beta$ for all $\beta<\lambda$ by inductive hypothesis.

Anyway you can prove the result also remembering that if $\omega\le\alpha$ then it exists a unique $\beta$ such that
$$
\alpha=\omega+\beta
$$
so that if $1+\omega=\omega$ then through the associativity we conclude that
$$
1+\alpha=1+(\omega+\beta)=(1+\omega)+\beta=\omega+\beta=\alpha
$$

Comment: In the 3th case, assuming $\beta$ all the values ​​previous to $\lambda$, it could (must!) be natural number and each natural number $n$ is such that $1+n=n+1\neq$ $n$; so I ask: how to apply the inductive hypothesis?

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro $\sup_{\beta<\lambda} 1+\beta=\sup_{\omega\leq\beta<\lambda} 1+\beta$, so you don't need to worry about it

Comment: Sorry, can you explain this? Why it could or must only be $\beta>\omega$?

Comment: Because we're taking the sup, so it doesn't matter if we forget about some small values

Comment: What you say seems obvious to me, however for how hard I try I don't see a formal reason. So how do you see this formally?

Comment: It should be clear that $\sup_{\omega\leq\beta<\lambda}1+\beta\subseteq\sup_{\beta<\lambda}1+\beta$. Can you show that the other inclusion holds, remembering that the sup of a set of ordinals is the union of all ordinals in that set?

Comment: Perhaps it is possible to demonstrate this through this chain of equality?                     $\bigcup_{\beta<\lambda}(1+\beta)=[\bigcup_{\beta<\omega}(1+\beta)]\cup[\bigcup_{\omega\le\beta<\lambda}(1+\beta)]=\omega\cup[\bigcup_{\omega\le\beta<\lambda}\beta]=[\bigcup_{\beta<\omega}\beta]\cup[\bigcup_{\omega\le\beta<\lambda}\beta]=\bigcup_{\beta<\lambda}\beta$